# Running Python in Atom Windows 10

Tags: python, atom-editor

I've installed Python 3.5 on my computer along with Atom. I selected Python in the bottom right and quickly wrote  `print ("Hello World")`. However, I get an error message that says `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.364s]`

I have looked up solutions online. I have edited the init file in atom as well as the environment variable path, with the path to python. Lastly, I have edited the "Command" field in the "Script" package to include Python3.

The code I placed on the init file is `process.env.path = ["C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2",process.env.PATH].join(";")`

Links to where I found my solutions:

https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-get-python-to-run-from-atom-on-windows/15585/11

http://www.siliconcreek.net/computers/running-python-in-atom-io-in-windows

quora.  com/How-can-I-run-Python-in-Atom

I am using a new windows surface, and am setting up my development environment for the first time on this computer. Please help.

Comment: If you installed Python 3.5, wouldn't the directory be `C:\Python35\ ` not `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2`?

Comment: Does `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2` contain `python.exe`? Why can't you modify the regular environment variables?